# Read the array inside the query scope

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have an array in $genreArr, i want it to be readable in the line whithin the function(query) inner select:

```
    if($genreArr){
        $movies = DB::table('movie_list')->whereIn('movie_id',function($query){     
            $query->select(DB::raw('movie_id'))
                      ->from('movie_genre')
                      ->whereIn('genre_id',$genreArr)
                      ->distinct();
        })->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(10)->get();
    }
```

How do i do that without using global variables, i tried pass that variable as the second param next to the $query and than it gives me this kind of error:

```
Missing argument 2 for MovieController::{closure}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust the closure to `use` the variable you want.

```
function ($query) use ($genreArr) {
... ->whereIn('genre_id', $genreArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the `whereIn` method will accept this. But rather than using a closure, you could use an alternative callable option. i.e Something like

```
$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->setGenreArray($genreArr);

$movies = DB::table('movie_list')->whereIn('movie_id',array($obj, 'getQuery'))->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(10)->get();
```

And then you're query builder stuff will be inside the getQuery method, with access to the property `$this->genreArray`